# Horizontal/Vertical partitioning and relations

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, partitioning

I've got a question regarding horizontal/vertical partitioning in a relational database.

I'm gonna demonstrate with an example:

Let's say we've got a disjoint inheritance for Person. A person can either be registered, or unregistered, but not both.

A person also has a many-to-many relation with the table House, a house can be owned by 1..* persons, and a person can own 1..* houses.

If I then were to horizontal partition the Person table, which means we have a two identical tables, but one containing the registered persons, and one containing the unregistered. How would it work with the many-to-many relation?

I've thought of also partition the relationship, but if there's an n amount of relations between person and other tables, a horizontal partition would cause the tables to grow by n * 2. Is this really the way to go?

I hope I made myself clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "right way" to do this. There are different approaches with different trade offs. However, I would start with something like this:

```
               +------+          +-----+
               |Person<----------+House|
               +^----^+          +-----+
                |    |                  
                |    |                  
+---------------++  ++-----------------+
|RegisteredPerson|  |UnRegisteredPerson|
+----------------+  +------------------+
```

Person would have an autogenerated PersonID. The child tables RegisteredPerson and UnregisteredPerson would have the same Primary Key (making the relationship 1 to 0 or 1).
It is slightly tricky with this approach to enforce a Person having exactly one RegisteredPerson or UnRegistered person. The most straightforward way is to only allow write access to the tables through stored procedures that maintain the correct invariants. There are also schemes using triggers and tagging the Person record with the subtype.

Answer (score 0):

A note on terminology:  in the context of databases, "horizontal" and "vertical" partitioning usually refer to storage mechanisms that are entirely unrelated to your question.  This is a question about inheritance.

Laurence's answer is correct, as far as it goes.  You need an entity called `Person` for the relationship to `House` as you have described the problem.  Two ways of enforcing the "only-one" registration is to store the ids in the `Person` table.  One way is:

```
create table Person (
    . . .
    RegisteredId int references RegisteredPersons(RegisteredPersonId),
    UnregisteredId int references UnregisteredPersons(UnregisteredPersonId),
    check (RegisteredId is null or (UnregisteredId is null)
)
```

(Note this allows a person to be neither registered nor unregistered, although the `check` can be fixed for that.)

An alternative is:

```
create table Person (
    . . .
    RegType varchar(255),
    RegId int
    check RegType in ('Registered', 'Unregistered')
)
```

Then, depending on the database, you can define a computed column or view that defines the foreign key reference.  Something like this:

```
    RegisteredId as (case when RegType = 'Registered' then RegId end),
    UnregisteredId as (case when RegType = 'Unregistered' then RegId end),
```

Advantages and disadvantages.  The first approach enforces the foreign key relationships.  However, it eats up an integer of storage for each type.  For two types, this isn't a big deal.

The second approach requires functionality that is not standard across databases.  For instance, in SQL Server and Oracle, you can enforce the foreign key relationship -- but one does it with computed columns and one does it with filtered indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative post regarding the disjoint inheritance. However, what I was really asking about was how partitioning of tables with relations works.

Comment: @LinusEsbjörnsson . . . Horizontal partitioning disperses the rows of a table into separate storage spaces based on the values in a key column. I'm an quite unclear as to how this relates to your question.